# Why do phpinfo() and the php command show different .ini file paths?

Tags: php

I have just spend some time trying to figure out why a setting from my `php.ini` wasn't correctly loading, when I know for sure I have changed it in the file.

After finally trying out the good old `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` code through a PHP file, as opposed to previously reading the output from the `php -i` command in the console, it turns out the paths are different.

`phpinfo()` output:

```
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
+ Configuration File (php.ini) Path  + /etc/php5/apache2              +
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
+ Loaded Configuration File          + /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini      +
+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

`php -i | grep "php.ini"` output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

But why does this happen, why are there two configurations, and why are these two environments using separate ones? Also, shouldn't the `php` command be the same one that Apache2 is using when it executes scripts, and therefore load the same `ini` file as when being executed from the console?

Comment: see this http://serverfault.com/questions/645755/differences-and-dis-advanages-between-fast-cgi-cgi-mod-php-suphp-php-fpm for the differences between the multiple PHP environments PHP-CLI is just another one, with a different ini file

Comment: Why does it happen? Because certain ini options apply only to web access, and others only to command line access.... so each SAPI has an API customised to its own situation. e.g. superglobals like $_SERVER only exist for webserver SAPIs, and not for command-line